# Target a model class with a different name than the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity "orders" which is used for administrative views to access all orders in the system.

I want to use the same entity to allow non-administrative users to view and manage their own orders.

My methodology would be to create a controller called userorders to keep everything separate from the existing orders controller. This controller would target a view model named "userorders". However, the entity and table name is "orders", so I'm not able to create this controller.

Is it possible to create a controller that targets the orders entity but has a different name?

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What does 'so I'm not able to create this controller' mean? Are you getting errors or are not sure what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably create a UserOder view model for that case and when you are ready to persist your UserOrder, convert it back to your Order entity.

There are no reason you could not create a controller to manipulate those UserOrder, since Entity is only used to hide the direct database manipulation.